# Cordova App Change MainActivity Layout

Tags: android, cordova, android-layout

I'm going to ask it straight : 
I'm facing a problem and its that I need to add something to my mainActivity layout file ( to be more specific , some kind of extra space alongside cordova webview to display advertisements ) and after a while searching on google , it seemed like that I need to change my main.xml layout file ( placed in /res directory ) ( [Link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en) ) 
but such file does not exists in my cordova project directory !

how can I create this file and apply changes to it?

Note : It doesn't make a difference but knowing the fact that I'm using [Ludei WebView+](https://github.com/ludei/webview-plus/) to improve performance on android 4.x version

Comment: How did you solved your question? please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements).
This document is for phonegap but I think will be helpfull ;)